# Raspberry Pi 3 on Android Things OS for 40 inch display (Graphics Issue)

Tags: android, gpu, overclocking, android-things

I am working on a project where I need to run videos on a 38"-40" inch LED TV. Mp4 (720p) videos don't run as seamlessly as needed. It is not the worst in the world but I can see that it is missing frames (less fps). These same videos were working seamlessly on omxplayer in Raspbian. Need better video quality with Android Things? How should I overclock or get better GPU performance? I have tried android:hardwareAccelerated="true" in android manifest. Not much of a difference

Comment: Have you looked into filing something on the Android issue tracker?

Comment: Yeah, I'm going to do that now. Just wanted to check if someone knew of this bug already. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I installed Android Things on a Raspberry Pi 3 before and run some simple app, the graphics are laggy.

I thought it is due to Raspberry Pi 3 low GPU performance issue but turns out, the same app is running smoothly on other distribution like Lineage OS and Emteria.
Maybe Android Things is not meant for this kind of GPU intensive job.